# Windows Admin Center - Add Azure Network adapter

Tags: windows, azure-virtual-network

Want to setup a Azure Network adapter on a Windows Server 2019 DE machine. However, it does not matter what I try, the same error occurs:

> Error: Virtual Network Gateway submission
>
> Message Failed to submitted the update request of Microsoft Azure
>   Virtual Network Gateway WAC-Created-vpngw-99, Detail error message
>   from Azure: The BgpPeeringAddress for the virtual network gateway
>   /subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/Nett/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/VPN-Gateway
>   cannot be modified

Also tried to Configure BGP ASN on the Azure gateway adapter, with an ASN number in the private range. No luck.

Any help will be grately appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `BgpPeeringAddress` for the virtual network gateway is a specific IP address, which is the **second last address** from the GatewaySubnet range. The [official DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-bgp-overview#what-address-does-azure-vpn-gateway-use-for-bgp-peer-ip) states this:

> The Azure VPN gateway will allocate a single IP address from the
>   GatewaySubnet range defined for the virtual network. By default, it is
>   the **second last address** of the range. For example, if your
>   GatewaySubnet is 10.12.255.0/27, ranging from 10.12.255.0 to
>   10.12.255.31, the BGP Peer IP address on the Azure VPN gateway will be 10.12.255.30. You can find this information when you list the Azure VPN gateway information.

I can reproduce your issue, when I change the `BgpPeeringAddress` to an invalid IP address `172.24.1.250`. A valid IP address should be IP address `172.24.1.254` in my GatewaySubnet range `172.24.1.0/24`

[image]

I check this via [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/). You can get more details from this [blog](https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/azure-what-the-bgp-is-going-on-there/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the Resource Explorer. It was very useful. 

Set up a new, and working point-to-site solution in an another subscription/vnet, and compared the settings using the Resource Explorer.
Obviously, there is something with the bgpPeeringAddress. It is the only difference. 

Thank you for great help.